# REDIS : Searching based on object properties

Tags: redis

I am trying to figure out how to use REDIS for searching through all objects that match a criteria.

```
Object: key1: value, key2: value, key3: value

Criteria: 
{ key1 : A } returns all objects containing A as value for key1
{ key1: B, Key3:1 } returns all objects containing B as value for key1 and 1 for key3. Key2 could contain any value or null.
```

Crtieria is also a collection or list. I need to run a query that return all matching objects for each element in the criteria collection. i.e. a list of lists.
Is there some example that I can be pointed to?

Comment: Yeah it has covered up everything. Is Redis your only option ? In Redis the basic idea is to build your own indexing to search for stuff

Comment: Smells like a Document-Oriented database. Try MongoDB

Comment: As Basit said, you have to maintain the index your self. The example above could be solve with sets. For each key, you will have a set that will contain all the objects that this key is present in. The you can use unions and intersections on the key set to get your results.